# Loading image from from internal storage into WebView for Android7+

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am using a webview to show images , it saves the picture into internal storage and then loads it and it works fine . then i realized it's not working for Android 7+ . it's because of UriExposedException .

I tried to use FileProvider like this :

```
String uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(contex,getString(R.string.file_provider),file).toString();
String b = "<html><head></head><body style=\"margin: 0px;\">" +
"<img src=\"" + uri + "\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", b, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

but still it doesn't work any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why are you using a webview to show images?  Use an ImageView. WebViews are extremely heavyweight, and should only be used where the only option is html.

Comment: @GabeSechan i am loading very big images like 1000*12000

Comment: Doesn't change the answer. You shouldn't be using web views. If necessary, put it in a scroll view. Although I would expect memory issues with that size image on many devices

Comment: i know but i wanted to show big images and be able to zoom it without getting OOM exception